# Asp.Net Web Forms App integrate into MS Teams

Tags: asp.net, webforms, microsoft-teams

I have a Asp.Net Web Forms app which I have built.  I would like to have it integrated into a MS Teams site, but im unsure which Authentication model to use with Teams.  I would like it to inherit/know if the user is authenticated in the MS Teams site, username, role etc...  MS Teams seems to be an iFrame, how will my app know that its within a MS Teams site.

Comment: Are you planning to integrate it in Teams channel Tab or Personal Tab or any other place?
Please provide more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.  I was looking to use teh method of:

Add a Tab > Website >  Give my website URL

I am assuming this method is rather basic and I need to create an actual app of some sort.  Really appreciate all your help

Comment: As per your requirement, you need to create a configurable tab with Tab SSO authentication.
You can integrate or show your application on that configurable tab.
Reference sample link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp